# Passport "Hello World" always fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I have the following:

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import {Strategy} from 'passport-local';
import pg from 'pg';
import {pgUri} from '../environment';

let loginRouter = Router();

passport.use(new Strategy((username, password, done) => done(null, true)));
//{
//    pg.connectAsync(pgUri)
//        .then(([client, release]) => {
//            return client.queryAsync('select * from users where "user" = $1::TEXT', [username])
//                .finally(release);
//        })
//        .tap(result => console.log(result.rows))
//        .then(result => done(null, true));
//}));

loginRouter.get('/', (request, response) => response.render('login'));
loginRouter.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/',
                                                      failureRedirect: '/login'}));

export default loginRouter;
```

It's an express route file that defines the simplest possible authentication scheme. The above always redirects back to `/login`, indicating a failure.

### What I've tried

- Changing `failureRedirect` to `/loginFailed` really redirects there. So the login does fail.
- Breakpoints and `console.log`s inside the function body do not get hit.
- Calling `done` with `done(null, {foo: "bar"})` instead of true changes nothing.

### Worth noting

- I'm using babel for ES6 support, but since this is the only part failing, and the breakpoints I can set (before `passport.use`) show expected values for all variables, I don't think that's the problem.
- The `.get()` route works as expected, displaying the form.

I have this in my bootstrap phase:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "some-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, {foo: "bar"}));

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => done(null, {foo: "bar"}));
```

Here's the form I'm using (directly copied from the **[passport example](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/)**)

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have no idea what went wrong here. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your passport code looks ok to me. Are you using anything to parse the POST body? See the 'Middleware' section on [this page](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) and check out the `body-parser` module [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Comment: Yep. That seems to have been the issue. It's a shame this things are not better documented. If you care to write this as an answer, I'll upvote/accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use something to parse the POST body.

Passport is designed to do literally one thing: authenticate requests. It delegates all other functionality—including parsing the POST body—to the application. They say this in their [overview](http://passportjs.org/guide/), but it's easy to underestimate the implications.

They come back to the topic in the **Middleware** section of their [Configure](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/) page, so I recommend reading that.

I happen to use the `body-parser` module to handle this (read about it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)).

Comment: They mention it in their code, but they don't reference this fact anywhere. Hopefully this will stand here to be helpful for people looking for it. Thanks!